# One recipi setting path for the recipes that depend on it

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have two recipes that add two packages that depend on each other. For example `exlib` which adds a library and a couple of header files. There is another application called `ex-calibrate` which uses the library and the header files. `ex-calibrate_0.1.bb` has the `DEPENDS = exlib` set. However, the `ex-calibrate_0.1.bb` `do_compile` fails because it can't access the header files that `exlib` provides.

Is there some bitbake "proper" way to provide this information between these two recipes?

Comment: If you can, post the entire recipes of exlib and ex-calibrate, as it can be a lot of mistakes.

Comment: you need to make sure that compiling exlib recipe all header files and library are populated in sysroot directory. Please post both recipes.

Comment: @KrupalTharwala: that was exactly the problem. Once `exlib` installed all the proper headers `ex-calibrate_0.1.bb` compiled fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if the `exlib` properly installs all the headers in the final target they will be available for use in `ex-calibrate_0.1.bb`. Which is what @Krupal-Tharwala suggested.